# How do I recreate this SQL in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

```
SELECT `av`.`answer_id`, SUM(IF(`av`.`helpful`=1, 1, -1)) as `score` 
FROM `questions_answervote` AS `av` 
JOIN `questions_answer` AS `a` 
ON `a`.`id`=`av`.`answer_id` AND `a`.`question_id`='775819' 
GROUP BY `av`.`answer_id` 
HAVING SUM(IF(`av`.`helpful`=1, 1, -1)) > 0
```

I have three models: `Question`, `Answer` and `AnswerVote`. Every Question has a set of Answers and every Answer has a set of AnswerVotes. AnswerVote has a field `helpful` which is a boolean.

What I am trying to do is get all the helpful Answers for a Question by calculating a `score` for each of the Answers (+1 for helpful=True, -1 for helpful=False). An Answer is helpful if it has a score > 0.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Post what you've tried and what does or does't work about it. [This is a *task* and not a *question*](http://whathaveyoutried.com) which still needs to be broken up into components and refined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following:

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    data = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)

class AnswerVotes(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer)
    helpful = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)
```

It may seem a bit like a work around but why simply not do an average of all votes helpfullness. Instead of -1 to 1 range, you will be somewhere between 0 and 1 with raw values in the DB. Simply treat 0.5 as the middle ground in your case and you should get the same behavior.

```
Answer.objects.annotate(score = Avg('answervotes__helpful'))

    {'score': None, 'id': 1, 'question_id': 1}
    {'score': 1.0, 'id': 2, 'question_id': 1}
    {'score': 0.5, 'id': 3, 'question_id': 1}
    {'score': 0.3333333333333333, 'id': 4, 'question_id': 2}
    {'score': 0.5, 'id': 5, 'question_id': 3} 
    {'score': 0.4, 'id': 6, 'question_id': 3}

Answer.objects.annotate(score = Avg('answervotes__helpful')).filter(score__gte=0.5)

    {'score': 1.0, 'id': 2, 'question_id': 1}
    {'score': 0.5, 'id': 3, 'question_id': 1}
    {'score': 0.5, 'id': 5, 'question_id': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's ORM doesn't do `HAVING`, so you will have to drop to raw SQL for this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can drop the `HAVING` portion of the query as the result set is usually fairly small and I can move that logic to Python. Do you know how I'd implement the rest of it?

Comment: You may be able to get away with [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), but the conditional *might* require you to use [`.extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

Comment: How would I implement this portion?

`SUM(IF(av.helpful=1, 1, -1))`

`helpful` is a tinyint and it stores a value of 1 or 0 (boolean), so I use an IF statement to treat the 0 as a -1 when summing.